# The SELECT statement includes a reserved word

Tags: vba, ms-access

So when I try to run my code I get a Runtime Error '3141' "The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect."

Here is my code

```
    strSQL5 = " SELECT DatePart('m',[gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly]![Test_Date]) AS Char, MonthName(DatePart('m',[Test_Date])) AS [Month], DatePart('yyyy',[Test_Date]) AS [Year], Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].LeaksLogged) AS LeaksLogged, Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].[ME Samples]) AS [ME Samples], Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].MSampleLogged) AS MSampleLogged, Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].Saddle) AS Saddle, Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].EntranceDia) AS EntranceDia, Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].TappingTee) AS TappingTee, [gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].LDIW, [gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].[X-Ray], [gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].[ETSP Inspection], [gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].DFT, [gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].CDT, Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].[Mount Photos]) AS [Mount Photos], Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].[Melt Index]) AS [Melt Index], Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].PSampleLogged) AS PSampleLogged, Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].Density) AS Density, " & _
 " Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].PE_WT) AS PE_WT, Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].OOR) AS OOR, " & _
 " Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].Poly_OD) AS Poly_OD, Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].[WaterBath Out]) AS [WaterBath Out], Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].[WaterBath In]) AS [WaterBath In], Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].FTIR) AS FTIR, Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].OIT) AS OIT, Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].[Steel WT]) AS [Steel WT], Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].[Steel Hardness]) AS [Steel Hardness], Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].[Steel OD]) AS [Steel OD], Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].[TIMP Corrosion]) AS [TIMP Corrosion], Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].[Chem Analysis]) AS [Chem Analysis], Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].[Steel Mounts]) AS [Steel Mounts], Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].[Mounts Polished]) AS [Mounts Polished], Sum([gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly].Etch) AS Etch FROM [gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly] " & _
 " GROUP BY DatePart('m',[gs_MultiList_Daily/monthly]![Test_Date]), MonthName(DatePart('m',[Test_Date])), DatePart('yyyy',[Test_Date]) " & _
 " ORDER BY DatePart('yyyy',[Test_Date]) "
```

This is exactly how it is displayed on the window. The SELECT statement is really long and did not fit in a single line so I broke it up into 3 using " & _ " I also have spaces at both ends of the " so im clueless to where the error is coming from. Can someone please direct me to the correct path ? thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`CHAR` is a reserved word, don't use it as an alias (or add `[]` brackets, but really, don't use it).

Generally, when you encounter this error, run each field name through the [list of reserved words](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sql-reserved-words-b899948b-0e1c-4b56-9622-a03f8f07cfc8).

Comment: Fixed. Thank you Erik for the quick response!